# Два вопроса насчет машинного кода

Tags: cpu, процессор, машинный-код

1. Программа, записанная в форме машинного кода, выглядит одинаково для всех типов процессоров?
2. Программы, написанные на низкоуровневых языках, более производительные по отношению к программам на языках высокого уровня?

Answer (score 5):

#### 1

Не всегда программа выглядит одинаково для разных процессоров. Это зависит от [архитектуры набора команд](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4) (ISA). На этом уровне определяются все инструкции, которые может выполнять CPU, набор регистров, прерывания, модель памяти, модель адресации и так далее.

Таким образом, если два CPU имеют одинаковую ISA, то и программа в машинном коде выглядит для них одинаково. Например, и у Intel и у AMD есть процессоры, реализующие x86 ISA, таким образом, программа будет переносима между такими процессорами.

#### 2

Совсем не обязательно. Поймите, что в конце концов любая программа будет выполнена на CPU как набор инструкций. Поэтому производительность зависит от того, насколько оптимально программа в этот набор инструкций переведена.

Для примера рассмотрим какой-нибудь язык ассемблера и какой-нибудь компилируемый язык высокого уровня, например, C++. Если вы на языке ассемблера сможете написать код более оптимальный, чем тот, что будет сгенерирован компилятором C++, то ваш код будет работать быстрее. Если же компилятор сгенерирует более оптимальный код (что более вероятно), то быстрее будет работать скомпилированная программа.

Существуют так же *интерпретируемые языки*. Программы на таком языке не компилируются в машинный код, выполняемый непосредственно на CPU, а интерпретируются специальной программой *интерпретатором*. Опять же ваша программа предстанет перед CPU как набор инструкций, только сделает это через посредника — интерпретатора. Распространено мнение, что интерпретируемые языки медленнее, чем компилируемые, однако [это не совсем так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694402/why-are-interpreted-languages-slow).

Таким образом, нельзя сказать, что программы на языке низкого уровня быстрее, чем программы на языке высокого уровня. Производительность будет зависеть от того, насколько оптимально компилятор или интерпретатор «переводят» программу для того, чтобы CPU мог ее понять и исполнить.